# requestFeature() must be called before adding content (AdMob)

Tags: android, admob

I got this error and I don't know what causes this.
Can you help me wit this error?
How can I fix this?

*
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.app/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:352)
    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3759)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.ab.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:279)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.c.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:58)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfk$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) *

here's my xml code

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

an declared it on onFinishInflate of my custom view

```
 @Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
   mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
   adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: I declared AdActivityon manifest by the way



`<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />`

Comment: @RRR I didn't use `requestFeature` but still it get the error

Comment: Did you get a solution this? I am getting a crash with interstitial ads.